# How is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The question [How can I highlight matches using GNU grep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66/pimp-my-gnu-grep) got closed for being too broad. I would like to know why this question is considered as too broad? Was it because of the first edit today? Or for different reasons? Answer can hopefully improve my close-voting behavior.

Comment: I'm thankful it's no longer titled "Pimp my...". Sexual slavery and human trade are pressing yet unrelated issues.

Answer (score 4):

I started the close process (though originally as "primarily opinion based", not "too broad") on that question because it popped up on the front page because someone posted a new answer.
The version of the question [as of then](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/66/3) had a title of "Pimp my GNU grep", and a body containing "How do you configure GNU grep best" which is very subjective. Most of the answers were also supporting this as they had basically become everyone's favorite way of using `grep`.

So the close was because it was a subjective question, and to get people to stop posting answers to it.
Additionally, closing sends a message that such questions are not a good fit for the site, while still keeping it around as it has value. Otherwise people see the question, and think they can ask ones similar to it.

Comment: That your name gets attached to a reason you did not pick when close-voting also bothers me a bit.